# office web api create blob from octetstream and create a new workbook from it (javascript) (ms excel)

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

I'm trying to create a workbook based on a server REST API response (octet-stream), but I'm failing to create one.

Here's the snippet for my create workbook function:

```
async function createWorkbookFromExisting(myBlob) {

  OfficeExtension.config.extendedErrorLogging = true;
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    Excel.run((context) => {
    // strip off the metadata before the base64-encoded string
    const startIndex = reader.result.toString().indexOf("base64,");
    console.log(startIndex);
    const mybase64 = reader.result.toString().substr(startIndex + 7);
    //console.log(mybase64);
  Excel.createWorkbook(mybase64);
  return context.sync();
});
};
```

and here's my blob creation snippet:

```
xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  //var a;
  if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState === 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status === 200) {
    console.log(xmlHttpRequest.response);
    var respObj = new Object(xmlHttpRequest.response);
    //xmlHttpRequest.re
    console.log(respObj);
    var resp = new Blob([xmlHttpRequest.response], { type: 'application/ vnd.openxmlformats - officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;'});
    
    createWorkbookFromExisting(resp);
    
    
  }
};
xmlHttpRequest.open("GET", _url);
//xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/octet-stream");
xmlHttpRequest.responseType = 'blob';
xmlHttpRequest.send();
```

I'm having this error:

{
"description": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
"message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
"stack": "InvalidArgument: The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.\n   at Anonymous function (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/excel-win32-16.01.js:26:287669)\n   at o (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/static/js/1.0f9cfae3.chunk.js:1:2779072)\n   at Anonymous function (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/static/js/1.0f9cfae3.chunk.js:1:2779219)\n   at u (https://script-lab-runner.azureedge.net/static/js/1.0f9cfae3.chunk.js:1:314565)",
"name": "RichApi.Error",
"code": "InvalidArgument",
"traceMessages": [],
"innerError": null,
"debugInfo": {
"code": "InvalidArgument",
"message": "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format.",
"errorLocation": "Application.createWorkbook",
"statement": "var createWorkbook = application.createWorkbook(...);",
"surroundingStatements": [
"var workbook = context.workbook;",
"var application = workbook.application;",
"// >>>>>",
"var createWorkbook = application.createWorkbook(...);",
"// <<<<<",
"createWorkbook.open();"
],
"fullStatements": [
"var workbook = context.workbook;",
"var application = workbook.application;",
"var createWorkbook = application.createWorkbook("dW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZmluZWQ9JnVuZGVmaW5lZD0mdW5kZWZpbmVkPSZ1bmRlZm

Comment: Can I know how did you run these code ?  Can you share a sample of resp mentioned in your code to help repro ?

Comment: Hi @MandytMSFT, I ran it using scriptlab

Comment: Is that possible to share your sample of resp in order to focus on identifying the cause of API error ?